# Can you have a variable within a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I need to do something like this:

Section 1, Chapter 1 title is "Dogs"

Section 1, Chapter 2 title is "Cats"

Section 2, Chapter 1 title is: "Goldfish"

I want to be able to write it something like this, with arrays:

```
section[0].chapter[0] = "Dogs";
section[0].chapter[1] = "Cats";
section[1].chapter[0] = "Goldfish";
```

Comment: Yes.  What trouble are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This other post on stackoverflow has some answeres on how to create 2-dimensional arrays.
[How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-to-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Or you could use a "class", though this may be needlessly complex...

```
function Section ()
{
  this.Chapters = new Array( 10 );
}

function CreateSection ()
{
  var sections = new Array ( 10 );

  sections[0] = new Section ();
  sections[0].Chapters[0] = "dogs";

  alert (  sections[0].Chapters[0] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The multidimensional array is what I'm looking for... I saw an example on it before but it didn't seem to work, the approach was a little different.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like a Multi Dimentional Array?

[How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-to-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)